# How can I prevent a part from being added to any stage?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program many parts, typically engines and separators are "stagable", in that their activation can be tied to a stage.  However sometimes I have stagable parts that I don't want tied to any stage, for example [Sepatrons](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Sepratron_I) that I want to use to use as part of my [Abort action group](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Action_group).  The game seams to automatically put these parts into a stage, is there a way I can prevent them from being staged, to be activated as part of an action group or manually?

Comment: I would suggest putting them after your last stage, so that you'll never actually use them except in the Abort action group. By the time they come up in the staging list, they'll no longer be attatched to the rocket (hopefully) and you won't have to worry about accidentally staging them.

Comment: @EliasBenevedes I wouldn't know any other method. You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no method or option to prevent this default behaviour.

Workarounds:

As Elias said, one method is to put these modules at the top of the staging queue so they don't get fired, but for that you must make these groups first, or move them manually to the top when you do them last. This leads to...

Simply remove them after they are being added from the staging queue.
When you build these parts last, just completely remove the last (first to be activated) part of the queue.

Comment: How would I remove them from the staging queue? What should I click?

Comment: You just drag the Symbol off the queue

Comment: Could you just have the Sepratrons at Stage 0?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Advanced Tweakables in the options, some stageable parts (but not all of them) will have a staging toggle. I use this often for Stack Separators and Fairings, since I'll deploy my payload manually once I'm in position, regardless of what stage I happen to be at.

A small issue is that the logic on the buttons is not consistent. For Fairings, the button is labeled with the current state (Fairing Staged VS Fairing Not Staged). For Stack Separators, it's the opposite: the button is labeled with what clicking the button will do (click to Enable Staging VS click to Disable Staging).

And unfortunately, I see no such options for Rocket Engines.